# How to calculate Normals Vector based on surface angles using javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, vector

I have these 3 (a, b and c) angles for a surface shown in the picture and I need to find the (x,y,z) for these two normal vectors.

One of the vectors is laying over the surface and the other one is perpendicular to it.

And vectors are pointing outward the origin (0,0,0).

Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: Need more info. What are a,b,c relative to? (eg the x, y, and z axis???). Also I am guessing you want to find (the non unique) (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2). Is that correct? (I say this, because from what you have said it appears the origin will always be on your surface. Is that what you want? It should not effect the two vectors though.)

Comment: Yes @Rewind, the angles are relative to X, Y and Z axis. I need the normal vectors if I am right it means that it will always be in scale of 1 in every component. And the origin is always located in the centre of the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only use basic rotations, you have the straightforward formulas for each rotation :

[image: wikipedia's formulas for basic rotations]

The rotation you want to operate is the multiplication of these matrices. The order is important, but because you get your angles from a gyroscopic device, I will assume a conventional order of : roll (around x axis, a or gamma in this post's notations), pitch (around y axis, b or beta), and finally yaw (around z-axis, c or alpha).

Here is the general explicit (and pretty ugly) matrix formulation for you, showing in which order the three rotations have to be performed (from http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html).

[image: direct formulation of R]

You then multiply your vectors by this matrix R (with your vector as a column vector on the right-hand side), and you're done.

So you javascript code for the matrix is :

```
var ca = Math.cos(a), sa = Math.sin(a);
var cb = Math.cos(b), sb = Math.sin(b);
var cc = Math.cos(c), sc = Math.sin(c);

var mat = [[cc*cb, cc*sb*sa-sc*ca, cc*sb*ca+sc*sa],
           [sc*cb, sc*sb*sa+cc*ca, sc*sb*ca-cc*sa],
           [-sb,   cb*sa,          cb*ca]];

// x is any vector you want to rotate
var x = [/* value on x axis */, /* value on y axis */, /* value on z axis */];

// this is the value of x once it is rotated
var rot_x = [mat[0][0]*x[0]+mat[0][1]*x[1]+mat[0][2]*x[2],
             mat[1][0]*x[0]+mat[1][1]*x[1]+mat[1][2]*x[2],
             mat[2][0]*x[0]+mat[2][1]*x[1]+mat[2][2]*x[2]];
```

---

You can see from the general formula that if you rotate the vectors of the standard basis, you get the first column of the matrix for [1,0,0], the second column for [0,1,0] and the third column for [0,0,1], which is simpler. However the above formula is general and always works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I do not really know how to do this in Javascript and I don't have any order for these angles. I get these angles as an output from a gyroscope device which tells me how my surface is angled in alpha, beta and gamma angles. alpha is rotation around Z axis, beta around X axis and gamma around Y axis.

Comment: @RojanGh. updated with naming conventions and code. The last part is simply matrix-vector multiplication, and you can see it simplifies a lot if you know your original vectors have some `0` values.

Comment: So @Cimbali you mean that x1 is the origin right? And also I could not figure out how to get the perpendicular vector. I am assuming that this one is for the one on the surface, right?

Comment: `x` can be any vector you want to rotate. It can be `[1,0,0]`, `[0,1,0]`, `[sqrt(2), sqrt(2), 0]` ... so just put the values of your vector and use the formula.

Comment: can you explain what axis (x,y,z) should I map (a,b,c) to please? What the gyroscope gives me is: rotation around Z axis is "alpha", around X axis is "beta" and around Y axis is "gamma" but I am not sure which one I should use for these 3 from a,b,c you used. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Great, I really want to mark this as the answer, just one last question, I am confused on how to find the two vectors. Assuming the origin is (0,0,0) and we have a:15, b:5, c:10, can you tell me how to get both perpendicular vectors shown in the picture, one lying on the surface and the other perpendicular to the surface. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: If your angles are in degrees, you must multiply them by `Math.PI/180` before running the code above. To get a vector that is in the plane, start with x=[1,0,0], and for one orthogonal start with x=[0,0,1]. Then apply the formula.

Comment: That is correct, since gamma is the rotation around the vector that you use for x1.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
[x1] = [cos(b)cos(c)]
[y1] = [sin(c)cos(b)]
[z1] = [-sin(b)]


[x2] = [sin(b)cos(a)cos(c) + sin(a)sin(c)]
[y2] = [sin(b)sin(c)cos(a) - sin(a)cos(c)]
[z2] = [cos(a)cos(b)]
```

where a=rotation around x-axis, b=rotation around y-axis and c=rotation around z-axis.

Extra Credit Answer:

If (x3,y3,z3) is another vector ON the plane perpendicular to (x1,y1,z1), then it is as follows:

```
[x3] = [sin(a)sin(b)cos(c) - sin(c)cos(a)]
[y3] = [sin(a)sin(b)sin(c) + cos(a)cos(c)]
[z3] = [sin(a)cos(b)]
```

Explination:

(I am using UK definitions of matrices in my explination, so US people remember you typically do it back to front. It does not effect the result, just the explination.)

I am assuming your plane starts flat on the table, it is the x-y plane. The z-axis points out of the page. You rotate a-degrees around the x-axis, b-degrees around the y-axis and c-degrees around the z-axis.

So think of your (x1,y1,z1) vector as the vector (1,0,0) rotated a,b,c in order. Similarly (x2,y2,z2) is the vector (0,0,1) rotated through a,b,c in order. (If you wanted another vector on the plane itself perpendicular to (x1,y1,z1) just do the rotations on (0,1,0)).

Here are the matrices that rotates around the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis in order. Where c = cos of the angle and s = sin of the angle

```
[1 0 0]
[0 c -s]
[0 s c]

[c 0 s]
[0 1 0]
[-s 0 c]

[c -s 0]
[s c 0]
[0 0 1]
```

So all we have to do is apply them one after the other (so US people do this in reverse order)

```
Final matrix = [cos(c) -sin(c) 0] [cos(b)  0   sin(b)] [ 1      0       0   ]
               [sin(c) cos(c)  0] [   0    1     0   ] [ 0    cos(a) -sin(a)]
               [0       0      1] [-sin(b) 0   cos(b)] [ 0    sin(a)  cos(a)]

             = [cos(c) -sin(c) 0] [cos(b)   (sin(a)sin(b))   (sin(b)cos(a))] 
               [sin(c) cos(c)  0] [  0           cos(a)         -sin(a)    ]
               [0       0      1] [-sin(b)  (sin(a)cos(b))   (cos(a)cos(b))]

             = [cos(b)cos(c)       (sin(a)sin(b)cos(c) - sin(c)cos(a))     (sin(b)cos(a)cos(c) + sin(a)sin(c))]
               [(sin(c)cos(b))     (sin(a)sin(b)sin(c) + cos(a)cos(c))     (sin(b)sin(c)cos(a) - sin(a)cos(c))]
               [-sin(b)                   (sin(a)cos(b))              (cos(a)cos(b))]
```

So then you multiply this matix by your vectors, which gives the answers above.

Comment: Very good explanation. I will try it and let you know if I could manage to use it in my situation. Thank you. :)